# Adding a search bar in main menu

Tags: macos

I am using mac os with objective C and XCode.My recent task is to add a search bar in main menu of mac desktop programatically.Could u please suggest me how to proceed with.Thanks

Comment: I wanna to more clearly explain on my question.I need to get the instance of main menu so that i can insert a search bar to the menu bar of the mac os using xcode and objective C..so how to get the instance of main menu.

Comment: hey if u don't know then please don't be vote for that.I think u r out of box to understand that question.

Comment: and what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To do this most easily, you require Mac OS X 10.5 or later.

The idea of a single menu bar is an illusion; it is a combination of two things: one that switches with the current application (a list of menus implemented by `NSMenu`, `NSMenuItem`, etc.), and one that doesn't change: the system's status bar (`NSStatusBar`).

If I understand correctly you want to call `[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar]` to obtain the main status bar (little icons in the corner of the screen) and add something to it, such as an icon that pops a menu.

You can use `NSStatusItem` to define something for this bar (e.g. to display a menu when clicked) and in your `NSMenu` definition you can add a view using `setView:` (this is the part that requires Mac OS X 10.5).  The view can be *anything*, including a search bar.

Comment: Thanks. Now I have Mac OS X 10.3.9. Exactly that is the two combination for to create( NSMenu, NSMenuItem)... I wanna to call that one and place a telephonic icon on that menu bar so that any user at any point of time directly call just by clicking the icon .But how to place the telephonic icon ,what u suggest i already tried but not able to place the icon to menu...Thanks

Comment: The only way to add an item is to let the system place it and return a new one (`[NSStatusItem statusItemWithLength:whatever]`).  You set an icon with the `setImage:` method of `NSStatusItem`, and set other properties as required.  If you can't insert a view into your menu because of 10.3.9, you can "fake" one in various ways (e.g. instead of opening a menu, create a transparent window in just the right location to give the illusion that something has appeared).

Comment: Thank you...Yaa that is the only problem due to old mac os x..I am trying in that way only by setting properties ..yaa right I need to fake..Let's see how I am getting accuracy(look & feel) by faking..ok anyway thank you once again.

Comment: The problem got solved...There was a mistake in setImage for icon setting  Kevin...Thanks Kevin Grant.